# I need specific ranges of information out of Excel files to Import into SQL

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am hoping someone can help me get started with a project. I'd say that my programming knowledge at one point was somewhere slightly beyond intermediate, but I'm rusty, old and haven't spent much time doing any serious coding since around 2005.

I have a folder full of hundreds of Excel files all structured the same way, but the data I need is not all columnar, but it is consistent. Here is an example of what I need to pull out of each excel file:

```
Row 1 = A24 thru L24, E16, J3, J5, J7
Row 2 = A25 thru L25, E16, J3, J5, J7
Row 3 = A26 thru L26, E16, J3, J5, J7
...
...
Row 25 = A48 thru L48, E16, J3, J5, J7
```

Then I need to grab the next file and do the same thing, appending to the table.

Since the Import wizard will import this file without issue and the data lines up consistently, I  could setup a batch file to read file names, execute a stored procedure in the database to import the data into a temp table, extract the data I need appending to the permanent table, wipe the temp, grab the next file, rinse and repeat.

The problem with that is that it's not efficient and I would like to learn something I can modify and use for other projects. Unfortunately, maybe I've gotten dense over the years, because I can't find a tutorial that matches what I have or what I need and I've been able to get like 20% - 30% there, but never close enough to make it the rest of the way with any given method.

The biggest problems I am running into with Tutorials, are that they either don't match my tools, don't seem to work at all, or don't explain the code enough to allow me to modify it effectively to get what I need out of it. I've spent more time dead-ending with more questions than answers than accomplishing anything really useful.

I am currently using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, SQL Server Express 2014 and I'm going to say that my choice in language would be VB if there is not an SSDT method for doing this. 
Any assistance in helping me grow a little bit and learn something that for whatever reason seems to be overly complicated,  would be greatly appreciated.

```
Edited to update information -
```

Once again, I am at a brick wall that I cannot seem to bypass. I have a 100% working package in SSDT and it works consistently. Now I need to loop through a folder with a few thousand files and import them all. I created a batch file to do this using DTexec, and I am getting the following error:

The connection "{58CC4865-DC6C-41BC-A475-6DA7098D61C0}" is not found.

I skimmed through the code in the XML for the package.dtsx and this is the connection ID for my SQL Server connection.

I have tried moving the connection manager files to the working directory with all of the scripts and the DTS package, I used the /Project option to point to my ispac file, no go.

When I try to deploy the package from within visual studio, it does not find my local instance. But it's there, I have it open in Management Studio, and I can execute the package successfully from within Visual Studio.

```
EDIT #2
```

I am now successfully parsing a directory full of excel files, renaming them to my DTS package target and then importing and processing them before moving on to the next file. I am using SSIS in Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server Express 2014, along with DTEXEC to execute my DTS package.

Trials and tribulations:

1 - IMEX=1 / Typeguessrows. I had data in a column that did not start until lower in the sheet, but I needed the whole sheet and did not want to try and mess with multiple ranges just yet.

Adding the setting IMEX=1 to the extended properties of the connection string for excel causes Excel to not insist on forcing INT datatype and NULLing your character strings. But even still, it only looks at the first 8 rows and Excel was choosing a Datetime value for one of my columns that had pricing information further down.

In order to fix that, I had to change the ACE connection driver settings in the registry to set TypeGuessRows = 0, (settings 0 - 16 to define number of rows) This allows it to look past the first 8 rows when setting the data type. A setting of 0  allows it to look at like 16k rows.

2 - Connection managers could not be found once I had built the DTS package and relocated it to my working directory for this project.

I read quite a few articles on possible problem/solutions, and at first I tried deploying to SQL, but it could not find my server and upon manually typing it in, I was told that this functionality was not supported before SQL Server 2016.

Then I tried to specify my *.ispac file using the DTEXEC /Project option and still, received the connection manager not found error.

I tried copying the connection managers along with the package.dtsx file to my working directory and that did not work either.

Finally I found a few mentions of converting to package deployment and eventually a tutorial on doing so allowed me to finally get past this. I converted my package, and then converted my connection managers to package deployment. Rebuilt the project and tried the new package.

3 - 64 bit DTExec vs. 32 bit ACE driver.

Since I am running on 64 bit and most of my tools and programs are 64 bit, my first attempt was to install the 64 bit version of ACE which is out there and is probably the best way to go if you can. Unfortunately for me, it requires uninstalling Office 32 bit and reinstalling as 64 bit and I don't have the media or license information to do so on my work computer.

That left me with the other option to go backwards on DTExec to 32 bit. I must have found 5 or 6 different articles leading me to the wrong install path and it's potentially due to different versions of SQL? Or Typos or something. In the end I did find it and a few other copies of it, all under "\Program Files x86\Microsoft SQL Server\130 (and 120 and 110)\DTS\Binn" And calling this tool explicitly by full path will use it instead of the 64 bit version.

In the end, I hate Excel. Not overly fond of Microsoft for cross compatibility between different versions of different software either, but I am getting used to the newer tools and finding the things I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSIS Excel connections allow you to define named ranges in Excel as your data source.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I was looking more for a tutorial relating to what I am trying to do, but I did manage to find an SSIS tutorial and I can get my data into SQL now. Now I have a different problem. At the top of the excel files, there are 3 fields merged with a date. Below that in the detail of the file those columns contain pricing, but when I import, all 3 columns are date/time values even if I change them to varchar/nvarchar in my table. Without using something like VB, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Hit another dead end... Cannot run the package with DTexec.